# POST data in server - angular 4

Tags: mysql, angular, angular4-httpclient

I have created a small program which is used to post the data and get the result back in the server.I have created a button in .html and function works fine.I am getting access log from the server side once I click POST button. But I couldnot display the data. Should I use GET function again or is there any simple way ?

```
app.component.ts

 import {Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers} from '@angular/http';
 @Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl:'app.component.html'
 })

 export class AppComponent {
 result;
 constructor (private http:Http) {

 }

 executeHttp() {
 var headers = new Headers();
 //this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 var content = JSON.stringify({
 name: 'my name'
 });

  return this.http.post(
 'http://100.000.00.000/webservices/voltage-info-service/server/server.php', content, {
  headers: headers
  }).map(res => res.json()).subscribe((data)

  => { '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><lfc:requests><lfc:request><lfc:busID>66</lfc:busID><lfc:timestamp>223456789</lfc:timestamp><lfc:coordinates>'+
    '<lfc:LongD>8</lfc:LongD><lfc:LongM>6</lfc:LongM><lfc:LongS>25.599</lfc:LongS><lfc:LatD>51</lfc:LatD><lfc:LatM>33</lfc:LatM><lfc:LatS>23.9898</lfc:LatS>'+
    '</lfc:coordinates></lfc:request></lfc:requests>';},

    this.result =data;
    console.log("data");  },
    err => { console.log(err); }
  );
  }
  }

  app.component.html

  <li>
    <button type="submit" (click)="executeHttp()">SOAP request </button>
  </li>
```

Comment: Is your server even returning data after handling the post request?

Comment: it should return a data..,as of now I ma getting only access.log in  the server side when I post the data

Comment: You must assign the post-data to a variable in your controller. `this.someVar = result`.

Comment: is that enough and where am i supposed to give the data to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a better approach would be if you make an attribute on the AppComponent, like 'result'.

```
 export class AppComponent {
   result;
 ...
```

Then in the subscribe next section something like:

```
.subscribe((data) => {
  this.result = data;
})
```

and then in app.component.html:

```
<div>{{result}}</div>
```

Comment: bear with me..,one more question.., where should i declare my data which i am supposed to post to the server

Comment: If you refer to the 'content', that depends where it comes from. Maybe from a form (FormGroup then), but in general also a variable in the class

Comment: I have made changes to .ts file above.,am I doing it correctly

Comment: I do not see clearly what that xml piece does there, i would do only: this.result = data; and delete that <?xml>.. After all it should come from the server should not it?

Comment: i have removed the xml part and did like you said..,it access the server log.,but there is no result from the server..

Comment: should I USE GET method..,to get result from the server

Comment: Enable Developer Tools in your browser. Check whether the response is what you expect. Get is fine.